# can not store data from api into variable with vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i try to store data from api in prometheus into global variable, i successfully store it from api into variable in vue js using axios, i tried to execute .then(console.log(this.infoCpu) and it worked in console, it has different value because it's from real time situation, but if i try to declare it with global variable on body html it does not work, the value if i try to console as global variable it will has null value, is it the null value comes from the value that i setup from the code on vue js? then how i store from data api into global variable that can be show if i try to show it, example code document.write("variable-that-contain-data-from-api") i need the variable because i use some library called gauge that need varibable contain data cpu real time from api

it is the code

```
 var newCpu = new Vue({
el: '#cpuHead',
data () {
return {
  infoCpu: null
}
},
mounted () {
axios
  .get('http://172.168.20.21:9090/api/v1/query?query=prometheus_tsdb_head_series_created_total')
  .then(response => (this.infoCpu = response.data.data.result[0].value[1]))
  .then(console.log(this.infoCpu))
}
})
```

that was the code that use to get data from api, and in console that is the right value of the variable this.infoCpu comes up at console.

but when i tried to show it at html body using document.write(newCpu.infoCpu), it does not has value, that just showing null default value that i set up on vue js code

but i try to show it using this code, it comes up

```
 <div id="cpuHead>
      {{ infoCpu }}
    </div>
```

[image variable work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpgrX.png)

so how to correctly save data from api into variable and use it into another library that i want to use, because it looks like does not mount data from api if try to show it with document.write(newCpu.infoCpu), i need the varibale to work with my gauge library that need a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to wait for response :

```js
const newCpu = new Vue({
  el: '#cpuHead',
  data () {
    return {
      infoCpu: null
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    await axios
      .get('http://172.168.20.21:9090/api/v1/query?query=prometheus_tsdb_head_series_created_total')
      .then(response => {
        this.infoCpu = response.data.data.result[0].value[1]
        console.log(this.infoCpu)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.infoCpu = error.message
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.25.0/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-/Q6t3CASm04EliI1QyIDAA/nDo9R8FQ/BULoUFyN4n/BDdyIxeH7u++Z+eobdmr11gG5D/6nPFyDlnisDwhpYA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="cpuHead">
  <div v-if="!infoCpu">loading ...</div>
  {{ infoCpu }}
</div>
```

Comment: it works in console, but when i try document.write(newCpu.infoCpu) it is just show undefined, i need the data from api is contain  in the global variable so i can set it in my gauge library, the example library code = gauge.set(the-variable-contain-data-from-api);  is it possible?